# Why isn't three.PointLightHelper working in my code?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The line `scene.add(new THREE.PointLightHelper(bluePoint, 3));` does not work in my code, which is below:

```
var bluePoint = new THREE.PointLight(0x0033ff, 100, 500);
bluePoint.position.set( 500, -500, 25 );
scene.addLight(bluePoint);
scene.add(new THREE.PointLightHelper(bluePoint, 3));
```

I have added the libraries: `Projector.js`, `CanvasRenderer.js`, `stats.min.js` and `three.min.js`

But it does work if I remove the line:

```
scene.add(new THREE.PointLightHelper(bluePoint, 3));
```

Why? Is there another way to increase the PointLight size in three.js without the `THREE.PointLightHelper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your console?

`scene.addLight` is not a function.

You want `scene.add(bluePoint)`

This runs for me on r71.